# Unexpected token , in statement SQL

Tags: sql, libreoffice, unexpected-token

I am using an odb file in LibreOfficeBase and trying to insert a bunch of rows at once.

I am using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID", "SubjectPersonID", "RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")
VALUES (11501, 9163, 'Parent Of',9165),
VALUES (11502, 9164, 'Parent Of',9165),
VALUES (11503, 9165, 'Child Of',9163),
VALUES (11504, 9165, 'Child Of',9164);
```

I get the following error:

> Unexpected token , in statement [,]

But when I take away the commas, I get an error

> Unexpected VALUES statement

I know the code is working because it does enter the first row before the [,]

The two answers I have seen given for this problem are:

1. It results from formatted text (i.e. written in something like Microsoft Word) - but I wrote this directly in the Command SQL box
2. It results from using a reserved key word - but I don't see what could be reserved in this code.

Comment: You need single `VALUES` => `INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")
    VALUES (11501, 9163, 'Parent Of',9165),
     (11502, 9164, 'Parent Of',9165),
     (11503, 9165, 'Child Of',9163),
    (11504, 9165, 'Child Of',9164);`

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz! I tried this - and it still gives me the unexpected comma error

Answer (score 1):

you have to omit second and beyond `values`. Try:

```
  INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")
    VALUES (11501, 9163, 'Parent Of',9165),
    (11502, 9164, 'Parent Of',9165),
    (11503, 9165, 'Child Of',9163),
    (11504, 9165, 'Child Of',9164);
```

Comment: Thanks!
This still gives me an "unexpected tpken: , in statement [,]" error.

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID") VALUES (11501, 9163, 'Parent Of',9165);
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")    VALUES (11502, 9164, 'Parent Of',9165);
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")    VALUES (11503, 9165, 'Child Of',9163);
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP_BTWN_PEOPLE ("RelationID","SubjectPersonID","RelationType", "ObjectPersonID")    VALUES (11504, 9165, 'Child Of',9164);
```

Comment: That depends on the DBMS in the background. If it's the standard HSQLDB (or Firebird for the most current version of LibreOffice) a single INSERT statement is possible as well.

Comment: I think this is the standard HSQLDB